# How to find a sub array in cakephp with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I have this problem with mongodb using cakephp. I don't know how to find a record with its sub-array.

I have this structure in mongodb

```
id:"xxx",
profile:[
{
    profile_pic:"xxx",
    firstname:"xxx",
    lastname:"xxx",
    slug:"xxx"
}
```

]

I pass on the slug variable in the controller and I want to get the corresponding record with its slug. I use this code:

```
$profile = $this->User->find('first', array('first', array('conditions' => array('User.profile.slug' => $this->request['slug']))));
```

But this code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aiyoh,

I had the wrong query in my profile. Should be:

```
$profile = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('profile.slug' => $this->request['slug'])));
```